# Debian Plesk Server: MySQL doesn't start

Tags: mysql, debian, plesk

I have a little Problem with a MySQL Server running on a Debian Server managed by Plesk. If I try to start the MySQL Server the following message is logged at `MySQL_error.log`:

```
150518 02:54:42 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
150518 02:55:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150518  2:55:15 [Warning] Using unique option prefix w instead of wait_timeout is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150518  2:55:15 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: option '--wait_timeout' requires an argument
150518  2:55:15 [ERROR] Aborting

150518 02:55:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

But I never modified my config file and I did never set a `--wait_timeout` argument.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention for this string:

"Using unique option prefix **w** instead of wait_timeout is deprecated"

Check that there is no "w" command argument or option in my.cnf.